# Creating Shapes Relative to World Position, Not Screen Position

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm sort of new to OpenGL and am looking to create a 2D game. I have found how to create shapes with `glBegin()`, `glVertex2f()` and `glEnd()`. However, when I use this, it uses the screen position for the co-ordinates (when I use a non-square display, the shape gets stretched).

So what I was wondering is, how would I create shapes relative to the world position, so it doesn't stretch to the screen (possible with `glm::vec2`)?

Comment: I know that it isn't an **exact** duplicate, but will end up using the same OpenGL API functions, `glOrtho()`, just through the C++ interface instead of Java.

Comment: Thanks man, glOrtho seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences and the fixed function matrix stack is deprecated since decades. See [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).
Read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

In OpenGL the normalized device coordinates in range [-1, 1] are mapped to the viewport. The projection matrix transforms the vertex coordinates from the view sapce to the clip coordinates. The these clip coordinates are also transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with w component of the clip coordinates.

By default the projection matrix on the fixed function matrix stack is the identity matrix. This leads to a 1:1 mapping of view space coordinates to normalized device coordinates. If the viewport is rectangular this has to be considered when setting the projection matrix.

An [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) can be set up by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

e.g.:

```
double aspect = (double)width/(double)height;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-aspect, aspect, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```